# Postgres top-k with ties

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, top

Assume I have the following DB table with 3 integer fields.

```
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 2 | 4
1 | 3 | 1
2 | 4 | 2
2 | 4 | 3
```

When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM dbTable ORDER BY A,B LIMIT 1;
```

I get

```
1 | 2 | 3
```

which is expected. But the 2nd record:

```
 1 | 2 | 4
```

also has the same values for dbFields A and B. Is there any efficient way to actually retrieve all records that have the same value as the top-k records? For example, when I search for the first 100 records to get instead 102 records if the last two have the same values as the 100th record? Is there any index to accelerate such queries? I do not mind if it has to be done with pl/pgsql (and not plain SQL) if the implementation is efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
/* Get the records of original table that correspond to each value of A 
and for values of B better or the same for the top-k records */ 
SELECT n3.A,n3.B,n3.C
FROM dbTable n3,
(
/* n2 = Get the worst value of B per A for the top-k records */ 
SELECT A, MAX(B) AS B
FROM 
/* n1 = Count records per A, ordered by B */ 
(SELECT A, B, C,
        row_number() over (partition BY A ORDER BY B,C)  AS counter
  FROM dbTable) n1

WHERE n1.counter<=100 /* k=100 */
GROUP BY A) n2

WHERE n3.A=n2.A AND n3.B<=n2.B
ORDER BY n3.A,n3.B,n3.C;
```

Seems correct, but please spot any possible oversight.

Comment: Too complicated. See my comment in horse's answer. And you should probably have `OVER (ORDER BY A,B)` there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for this:

```
select a,b,c
from (
  select a,b,c,
         dense_rank() over (order by a,b) as rnk
  from dbTable
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

For the "first" rows, it doesn't matter if you use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`. When you e.g. want the "second" ones, the `rank()` and `dense_rank()` would return different results in case of ties. Because `rank()` will have "gaps" in the numbers, but `dense_rank()` will not.

---

A possible speedup *might* be achieved by doing this in two steps and of course having an index on `(a,b)`

```
with ranked as (
  select *
  from (
    select a,b,
           dense_rank() over (order by a,b) as rnk
    from dbTable
  ) t
  where r.rnk = 1  -- (or <= for "top-k")
)
select t.a, t.b, t.c
from dbTable t
   join ranked r on r.a = t.a and r.b = t.b;
```

The idea is to give Postgres the chance to do an index-only scan for the ranking part and then join only the result of that to the base table to get the remaining column(s). The filtering on the rank is done inside the CTE as Postgres doesn't push down conditions from the outer query into the CTE itself (that's why I have the derived table inside the CTE)

I'm not sure if this really improves the performance, but I guess it would be worth trying and have a look a the execution plan with the real tables (and data).

Comment: +1 I have never heard of dense_rank before. Is there an index to accelerate this? Probably btree_gist must be, but I am asking if you know something else

Comment: An index on `(a,b)` will probably suffice.

Comment: But for `top k` this will not work. You could use `rank() over ...` and `where rnk <= k`

Comment: @ypercube. If I have a billion records, a b-tree index will retrieve all records, order them and get top-k. But this will be inefficient. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Indexes have the data in order. Not sure about Postgres details but `top N`, if properly implemented, it will only read the first N rows from the index.

Comment: @Alexandros: see my edit. By doing this in two "steps", this *could*(!) be faster. But you will have to check the execution plan with your real life data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will check it out, when I get to work. I will let you know and accept your answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I checked the first one (because I could understand that). The problem is that with your approach I get the first top-k values and not the top-k records + those corresponding to the last (worst) value. For example, I want the top-100 records. Let's assume that those 100 records correspond to 3 values. I need 100 records + some additional records that correspond to the third (worst) and not all records that correspond to the best 100 values, like your approach provides. I hope I am clear enough

Comment: @Alexandros: sorry, I have no idea what you mean. Can you add more sample data to your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No need to apologize. Thanks for your help and for teaching me dense rank. I think I have found a solution and will post it for future reference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think they mean that if they use `where rnk <= 100` your query will return the rows with top 100 values. If there are 3 rows for each value of 1 up to 100, the query would return 300 rows. But (if I understand correctly) they want the top 100 rows (so in the above example, the 102 rows, with values from 1 to 34. Because the 100th row would have value 34 and the two more tied rows would be included.) So they need `rank()`, not `dense_rank()`.